# Determine collision side of cube

Tags: javascript, collision, cocos2d-js

My cube can be on top of a platform but will die if he crashes into it.

When I had just a floor this worked well enough:

```
if(this.position.y > that.position.y) { 
    this is on top 
} else {
    this is not on top
}
```

When I introduced floating platforms standing on top still worked but if I jump against it my y would be higher than his y and it would think I'm on top.

Now clearly I have never heard of Math before and could use some help.

Note: I am using the cocos2d engine and Javascript but I don't think a solution is restricted by that.

Edit: To be clear. 
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsq5u.png)

I want to know how I can detect on which side the collision is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just detect your position when you start to jump

In that case, if - when you jump - your `Y` become bigger than the `Y` of the platform, you will have the choice to do what you want. Maybe stop the jump and go down, maybe go on top of the platform. You just need to know your starting point and add the condition you need

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. Maybe I wasn't clear so I updated the question.